# Any Visio templates for mocking up interfaces?

Tags: modeling, visio

I would like to use Visio to mockup a few ASP.NET interfaces that I can share with a client.  I know I can create these using Visual Studio, but I would rather use a graphics tool if possible.

I have Visio 2007 that came with MS Office and I do not have any software or database templates.  Does anyone know where I can find templates/stencils/shapes I can use for this?

If there are any other tools that I can use I'm open to that too.  I'm leaning towards Visio because I already have it and know how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Visio have an online template/shape search built in?

Comment: Surprisingly, not in the version I have (Visio 2007 SP2 MSO). Either that or I'm a moron and can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visio 2010 comes with a really nice set of wireframe shapes, but you have to buy the Pro or Premium versions, as Standard doesn't come with them.

Previous versions of Visio had some Windows UI shapes, but I'm not sure which editions included them. They are usually located in the "Software" stencils sub-directory.

I've also got a smattering of downloads on my site that might augment your UI collection. Have a look here:

http://www.visguy.com/category/visio-content/shapes/wireframes-ia/

Answer (score 3):

You can pull the parts from this PowerPoint template set: http://www.istartedsomething.com/20071018/powerpoint-prototype-toolkit-01/ and use them in Visio.